# Notepad++ regex to insert character every nth character from a starting position

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do you use regex to insert | every two characters from a starting position to the end of the line?

Using regex on the following sample (tshark output of packet data), the regex inserts | after the first two characters and the next two characters, but does not apply the pattern to the rest of the line. I think the issue is with a repeated pattern on the 2nd grouping (or lackthereof).

Sample:

```
1478646603.255173000    10.10.10.1  0000000000000000000000

^(.{34})(..) replace with \1|\2|   OR   ^(.{34})(.*?(..)) replace with \1|\2
```

Produces this:

```
1478646603.255173000    10.10.10.1  00|00|000000000000000000
```

What I want is:

```
1478646603.255173000    10.10.10.1  00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00
```

Comment: Why not a replace all with only `(..)` to `$1|` ?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't include all parts of my sample (time and IP). I've edited the post above for what the data looks like and what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^.{36})\K..(?!$)
```

and replace with `$&|`.

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^.{36})` - matches the location at the end of the previous successful match (with `\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the start of a line (`^`) and the first 36 characters other than linebreak chars (`.{36}`)
- `\K` - the match reset operator that discards the whole text matched so far
- `..` - any 2 chars other than linebreak chars
- `(?!$)` - that are not at the end of the string.

The replacement pattern only contains the backreference to the whole match (`$&`) and a `|` pipe symbol (a literal symbol in the replacement pattern).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked and that's perfect! Good explanation, too!

Comment: move the `\K` after the two dots.

Comment: You can also write: `\G(?!^)..(?!$)\K|^.{38}\K`

Comment: @AccessoryFreak: if you move it after the two dots, you can use `|` instead of `$&|` as replacement string. And more generally, what is the point to use `\K` if you have to put a capture group reference in the replacement string?

Comment: @AccessoryFreak: Casimir just wants to shorten the replacement pattern. I am not using *any* capturing groups in my pattern, thus, there is no overhead Casimir's comment implies, the `$&` backreference just points to the whole match. `\G(?!^)..(?!$)\K|^.{38}\K` will yield the same result as my regex.